# Crooked tree at the top. Bottom 50% is straight

Tags: trees

[image]

Hi all! We have a crooked tree we just planted about a month ago. The bottom of the trunk is straight but the top is crooked. It is a pin oak. What would you suggest doing to help it grow straight? Does anything need to be done? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks a nice little tree. With established trees, a prevailing wind can cause the trunk to bend. There's not much you can do about that. That isn't the case with your tree as you've only just planted it. I would just leave the tree to sort itself out, which it should do. I would also suggest that you widen the bare soil circle the tree is growing in to about a metre diameter so it's not competing for water and nutrients with the surrounding grass. You will need to stake the tree if the rootball starts rocking in the wind. Otherwise, don't bother. Advice about staking trees is given [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/types/trees/staking).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when young trees are planted they have 3 sticks on each side and something wrap around to hold the sticks. This are meant to hold the tree straight and avoid growth like this or wind from turning it down. There's different options like a tall pipe, stakes, bamboo or anything strong enough to be able to hold it. If there has been strong winds all this time then it might also explain why it grew side ways.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it just looks like a normal tree.  Not every tree grows absolutely straight up, it is part of its character.  While you could stake it at the moment, to try and straighten it, in a few years, it will be too tall and do what it wants to.